# AT commands and SAMSUNG modem

Tags: android, gsm, samsung-mobile, at-command

I installed Hyperterminal and I used my samsung galaxy s3 and connected it with my laptop with usb cable. I installed the drivers and computer detected s3 as modem. It shows connected in Hyperterminal. But whenever I send any command for example,

```
AT
```

and press enter, I don't get any response. I've tried configuring the connection according to the modem configurations and when I go to

Control Panel > Phone and Modems > Query

then I get success answer for all the commands.

Why aren't I getting any response in Hyperterminal?
I checked the user guide of the Samsung s3 and it supports AT commands. And it has a GSM Modem as well.

Comment: What settings does your serial connection have? Baud rate et al?

Comment: I tried use Baud 300,9600,57600, 230400. Data bits: 8. Stop bits: 1. Parity: none.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the python gsmmodem package.
I've connected my Galaxy S4 mini via a USB cable.
It comes up as /dev/ttyACM0
python gsmterm.py  -r '/dev/ttyACM0' -b '115200'

gives me a terminal where I can enter AT commands.

It seems to accept a limited subset since I'm also using a ublox gsm modem which has a very extensive command set.

Good luck,
Pete

Answer (score 1):

There are other options beside Hyperterminal.

You can connect to your Samsung modem with [Realterm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/), I use it everyday to communicate with modems of different brands Samsung, LGs, and ZTE using a long list of AT commands, and It helps me to verify the result that I get in Realterm matches with the apps I am doing.

It works well with the Galaxy S3 or any other Galaxy phone even the newer 2019 models . if you have installed drivers already, connect your phone on USB, once it has been recognized, just choose the COM  port where you are connected and you will be able to send AT+ commands.